Dependency Injection for DataStore with Koin
I have Compose multiplatform project that implement datastore. I use multiplatform datastore as reference. I have problem when injecting the data store.
commonMain :
fun getDataStore(producePath: () -> String): DataStore<Preferences> =
    synchronized(lock) {
        if (::dataStore.isInitialized) {
            dataStore
        } else {
            PreferenceDataStoreFactory.createWithPath(produceFile = { producePath().toPath() })
                .also { dataStore = it }
        }
    }

internal const val dataStoreFileName = "app.preferences_pb"

androidMain :
fun getDataStore(context: Context): DataStore<Preferences> = getDataStore(
    producePath = { context.filesDir.resolve(dataStoreFileName).absolutePath }
)

iOSMain :
@OptIn(kotlinx.cinterop.ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
fun createDataStore(): DataStore<Preferences> = getDataStore(
    producePath = {
        val documentDirectory: NSURL? = NSFileManager.defaultManager.URLForDirectory(
            directory = NSDocumentDirectory,
            inDomain = NSUserDomainMask,
            appropriateForURL = null,
            create = false,
            error = null,
        )
        requireNotNull(documentDirectory).path + "/$dataStoreFileName"
    }
)

and I have this class that access dataStore
class GameskiiSettingRepository(
    private val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>
) 

I don't know how to inject that dataStore and I keep getting this error
Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition 
found for type 'androidx.datastore.core.DataStore'. Check your Modules
configuration and add missing type and/or qualifier!


did you find an answer for this?

@furkanbzkurt unfortunately not yet, I'll update soon when I got the answer. Currently I still initiate it manually.

I solved this issue by declaring an expect actual koin module that instantiates the datastore. Your getDataStore signature is a little different but this should work for you as well.
Declare a preferenceModule in commonMain:
// commonMain
expect val preferenceModule: Module

Define the actual implementations for preferenceModule in androidMain and iosMain:
// androidMain
actual val preferenceModule: Module = module {
    single { createDataStore(androidContext()) }
}

// iosMain
actual val preferenceModule: Module = module {
// Here you don't need to pass null
    single { createDataStore(null) }
}

Add this module to the Koin initializer for both Android and iOS:
// androidMain
actual class KoinInitializer(
    private val context: Context,
) {
    actual fun init() {
        startKoin {
            androidContext(context)
            androidLogger()
            modules(
                appModule, viewModelModule, preferenceModule
            )
        }
    }
}

// iosMain
actual class KoinInitializer {
    actual fun init() {
        startKoin {
            modules(appModule, viewModelModule, preferenceModule)
        }
    }
}

Finally, provide the GameskiiSettingRepository dependency like this:
single { GameskiiSettingRepository(get()) }

Now you can inject this Repo into Viewmodel.
